# C# - Alto consumo de memória ao chamar método

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou trabalhando com um Form principal e nele tem diversos Panels. Em um deles, o "panelGeral" eu utilizo para chamar as instâncias de novos formulários e mostrar nele utilizando o seguinte código da classe FormCall:

```
public void chamaFormulario(Form form)
{            
        Form activeForm = frmMain.ActiveForm;
        foreach (Panel painel in activeForm.Controls )
        {
            if(painel.Name == "panelGeral")
            {
                painel.Controls.Clear();
                if(form != null)
                {
                    form.TopLevel = false;
                    painel.Controls.Add(form);
                    form.Show();
                }
            }
        }            
}
```

Por exemplo, quando o programa abre eu chamo um Form de boas-vindas da seguinte maneira:

```
private void frmMain_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmInicio frm = new frmInicio();
        formCall = new FormCall();
        formCall.chamaFormulario(frm);
    }
```

Quando eu chamo o Form frmClientes e, ao abri-lo, ele possui um botão "Voltar" que tem o objetivo de voltar a tela de boas-vindas, que chama o seguinte método:

```
private void btVoltarClientes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmInicio frm = new frmInicio();
        FormCall form = new FormCall();            
        form.chamaFormulario(frm);
    }
```

Mas observando o consumo de memória na ferramenta de diagnostico do VS2017 Community, o que estava consumindo 60MB sobre para 96MB, e caso eu abra novamente o form de clientes e aperte para voltar de novo, sobe para 136MB... E assim sucessivamente.

O que devo fazer para resolver este alto consumo memória?

Comment: Isto ocorre depois de você clicar no botão algumas vezes?

Comment: Maniero. Sim! Mas a solução do Rovann eu acho que resolveu o problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente ao remover os controles do painel (`painel.Controls.Clear();`) descartar os formulários:

```
painel.ControlRemoved += (ss, ee) => { ee.Control.Dispose(); };
```

Comment: Nossa, meio que resolveu o problema. Agora ta consumindo por volta de 38~55MB, testei clicando e clicando varias vezes. Seria essa a solução mesmo hehe?

Comment: sim, você está colocando os formulários dentro do painel, e quando remove, eles ainda estão instânciados e em memória... o `Dispose` irá descartá-los

Comment: Obrigado Rovann. Deu certo e resolveu o problema

Comment: Dei mais um porque soluciona o problema, mas isso é trágico, o ideal é rearquitetar pra não precisar mais fazer isso.